# difference between creating index with two columns and creating separate index on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, non-clustered-index

What is the difference between creating index with two columns and creating separate index on two columns?

Difference between

```
create nonclustered index ix_index1 on table1(col1)
create nonclustered index ix_index2 on table1(col2)
```

and

```
create nonclustered index ix_index1 on table1(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might experience a difference if you have any queries that select based on `col2` alone.

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE col2 = 'someValue'
```

If you have two separate indices, then there is a chance that `ix_index2` might be used to speed up this query.

However, if you only have a compound index on `(col1, col2)`, then that index cannot ever be used for this query. A compound index can **only** ever be used if the **n left-most columns** are being referenced in a query.

So your compound index might be used

- if your query uses both `col1` and `col2` in a `WHERE` clause
- if your query uses only `col1` in a `WHERE` clause

but it can **NEVER** be used if your query only uses `col2` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: What if the query do not use where clause at all?

Comment: Then your indexes are totally useless (unless you're using an `ORDER BY` clause that uses one of those columns - or both)